# What is the source of this error: "Because of security restrictions, the type <MyClass> cannot be accessed."

Tags: c#, remoting

I'm getting the following error when calling a method on a C# service (connected through .net remoting).

"Because of security restrictions, the type  cannot be accessed."

What is the source of this error?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you give a little more context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen other solutions for similar problems, but none of them were the same solution used to solve my particular problem.

Apparently I was missing an updated AssemblyInfo.cs file which includes the following statement:

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

This took care of the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Security Level for Remoting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61w7kz4b(VS.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229983.aspx

If it doesn't help, let us know the .net version you use.